# Не работают плагины Munin для Nginx после перехода на HTTPS

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, munin

После перехода на HTTPS перестали работать плагины Munin для Nginx. Сама страница со статусом Nginx прекрасно открывается через браузер, но при выполнении команды "munin-run nginx_status" по всем значениям выдается U.

Как подружить этот плагин с HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему изменением настроек плагинов nginx:

```
[nginx*]
env.url https://site.com/munin-nginx-status
env.port 443
```